# Does anyone know how this type of power supply works?

Tags: power-supply

I bought it with the intention to convert 110V to 120V AC to 2.8V with the current being adjusted. I am not sure which is the input and which is the output terminals. Also, I am not sure what all the terminals do/represent. Is there anything else about this power supply I should be aware of?
[image: Power Supply]

Comment: The in- and output terminals are very clearly labeled. I'll point out that it might be dangerous to connect this on your own if you don't have the necessary experience! Electrocution kills, and so do fires caused by unstable installations etc.

Comment: I agree with Marcus Müller about the risks of using such a device if you lack sufficient familiarity. However, for future reference, the N stands for Neutral, the L stands for Line, and the ground symbol stands for ground.  The screw terminals with these labels are connected to the Line, Neutral and Ground wires of your mains electrical supply. It can be fatal to connect these incorrectly. I would add, that these screw terminals are exposed, and it can be fatal to accidentally touch them. This includes with a metal screwdriver, if you touch the metal on the screw driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminals 6 & 7 (L and N) are line and neutral from the mains.  Terminal 5 is protective earth.  Terminals 1 & 2 are the positive output of the supply, presumably +2.8 V.  Terminals 3 & 4 are the negative or output ground reference for the 2.8 V.  As Marcus Müller points out, you may want to get some help from an experienced person  to be sure you hook this up safely.